# Comprehensively List HTTP Requests (IPs, URLs, etc)

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, httpd, process

Is there there a way to show a list of apache/httpd processes with their pids and some information about the request?  Like request url, any params, domain, internal/external IP address, etc.

I've tried things like `netstat` or `htop` but that doesn't tell me much information about what's going on.

I would like this so that I can pick and choose a process to kill rather than having to restart the service, which kills all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Set [`ExtendedStatus On`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html) in your `httpd.conf` and then run:

```
service httpd fullstatus
```

and you should get the information you're looking for, such as:

```
Server Version: Apache/2.3.8 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.3.8 OpenSSL/1.0.0a
Server Built: Aug 24 2010 23:25:11
Current Time: Thursday, 16-Sep-2010 19:20:09 UTC
Restart Time: Thursday, 16-Sep-2010 00:00:00 UTC
Parent Server Generation: 0
Server uptime: 19 hours 20 minutes 9 seconds
Total accesses: 8417703 - Total Traffic: 479.2 GB
CPU Usage: u114.008 s94.3594 cu0 cs0 - .299% CPU load
121 requests/sec - 7.0 MB/second - 59.7 kB/request
198 requests currently being processed, 186 idle workers
W_CC_KKK___KC__K_KKKK_KCK_K___K_KKK__K_K_K__C_KK_CKW_K_K_K____CK
KK_K___KKK_KKCK__K___K_K___KCK__K_KKKC__C__KKCCK_KCWK_KKCK_KKKKC
KC__K_KKK____KKKW____C_K_____C_K_KK________KK___C...............
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................

Scoreboard Key:
"_" Waiting for Connection, "S" Starting up, "R" Reading Request,
"W" Sending Reply, "K" Keepalive (read), "D" DNS Lookup,
"C" Closing connection, "L" Logging, "G" Gracefully finishing,
"I" Idle cleanup of worker, "." Open slot with no current process


    Srv PID Acc M   CPU SS  Req Conn    Child   Slot    Client  VHost   Request
    0-0 77149   0/155/14434 W 19.

63  1   0   0.0 1.06    726.43 205.231.104.48   activemq.apache.org GET /schema/core/activemq-core-5.1.0.xsd HTTP/1.1
0-0 77149   0/106/14490 _ 19.52 0   0   0.0 0.85    926.97 91.89.133.31 www.apache.org  NULL
```

Comment: Full status is giving me `Not Found. The requested URL /server-status was not found on this server.`

Comment: Did you restart Apache after you made the changes?